# What are the differences between Pit and Dark Pit?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I've tried out a bit of Pit and Dark Pit, but I can't tell much of a difference between the two characters. I know they're clones, so they're going to have mostly the same moveset, but even clones usually have *some* difference in this franchise.

What are the differences between Pit and Dark Pit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pit and Dark Pit are extremely similar to one another. Here are a list of the differences from [ssbwiki](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Dark_Pit_%28SSB4%29).

> - Dark Pit's Silver Bow arrows deal 2% more damage than Pit's Palutena's Arrows at full charge.
> - Dark Pit's Silver Bow also has slightly more knockback than Pit's Palutena's Arrow. However, It is slightly slower.
> - Dark Pit's arrows have less range and cannot be curved as dynamically as Pit's.
> - Dark Pit has no light rings to charge up his arrow.
> - Electroshock Arm deals strong horizontal knockback which KO's sooner than Pit's Upperdash Arm if hitting foes off the side blast
>     zones of the stage. It also does 0.5% more damage. However, it has
>     less vertical KO power.
> - Electroshock Arm also has the electric effect.
> - Forward tilt deals less knockback.
> - Dark Pit's Final Smash is different.
> - Dark Pit's victory theme and poses (including quotes), and taunts are different. His "NO CONTEST" pose is also different.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOkzx33aQF8) is a video displaying how incredibly similar these characters are.

Also, according to [these measurements](http://supersmashbros.wikia.com/wiki/File:Perfect_Pivot_Chart.png), Dark Pit's perfect pivot is about 12.5% longer than Pit's perfect pivot.

Comment: The perfect pivot's also differ